# Efficient for loop for numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, fft

[Data_File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ArImf4MiUt8T49LlY6RK7DdlGjv-G7uC)
I have a data frame of size [8192x29], i want to calculate the fft of each column but before that i need to reshape every column (8192 x 1) to (64 x 128). So for one column it goes like this

```
data_1 = np.array(data_all.iloc[:,16])
data_1 = np.reshape(data_1,(64,128))
data_standarized = preprocessing.scale(data_1)
fft = fftpack.fft(data_standarized)
```

Now i have to apply the same for all the data and hence "for loop" for all the columns and calculates the fft separatel. I can't seem to think an efficient way to do that. my for loop is as follows

```
data_k = np.zeros((64,3712))
for i in range(0,data_size[1]):
        data_k[0:63, i:i+127]= data_all[:,i].reshape(64,128)
```

Then i need another for loop to get the 64 x 128 matrix one by one and apply fft. In MATLAB if we have the structures we can do it with one for loop and every cell contains the output. Can we do something like this in Python?

Answer (score 0):

[`fftpack.fft`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.fft.html) will be applied to the last axis by default but you can specify any other axis as well:

```
data_new = data.reshape(64, 128, 29)
data_fft = fftpack.fft(data_new, axis=1)
```

Then you can reshape again if you like: `data_fft.reshape(64, -1)`.

Comment: data.reshape() ? it doesn't work and if i try in numpy it does not take 3 arguments. I want to do a lot of inbetween steps before taking the fft. If there is any other way to do that. Please i am open to ideas

Comment: @AR. What version of Numpy do you use? [The documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html) explicitly mentions that *"unlike the free function `numpy.reshape`, this method on `ndarray` allows the elements of the shape parameter to be passed in as separate arguments."*.